# Union Subquery produces Results Non-Unioned Subquery doesn't

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm using Access 2010 and i'm having a very strange query result.

I've created a query that includes a union subquery that produces results. I've also created a query that has a non-unioned subquery that doesn't produce any records. It's very strange because the union subquery is the non-unioned subquery twice.

Non-Unioned Subquery:

```
SELECT NVP, [NVP NAME], MIN([CURRENT PERIOD]) AS [MIN PERIOD], [BASE PERIOD]
    FROM AGGDATA 
    GROUP BY [NVP NAME],NVP,[BASE PERIOD]
```

Unioned Subquery:

```
SELECT NVP, [NVP NAME], MIN([CURRENT PERIOD]) AS [MIN PERIOD], [BASE PERIOD]
    FROM AGGDATA
    GROUP BY [NVP NAME],NVP,[BASE PERIOD]
    UNION
    SELECT NVP, [NVP NAME], MIN([CURRENT PERIOD]) AS [MIN PERIOD], [BASE PERIOD]
    FROM AGGDATA 
    GROUP BY [NVP NAME],NVP,[BASE PERIOD]
```

Here is the whole Query:

```
SELECT sub.NVP,sub.[NVP NAME], SUB.[MIN PERIOD], SUB.[BASE PERIOD], TT.[ACTIVE PERIODS]
FROM 
    (SELECT AGGD.NVP, AGGD.[NVP NAME], MIN(AGGD.[CURRENT PERIOD]) AS [MIN PERIOD], [BASE PERIOD]
    FROM AGGDATA AGGD 
    GROUP BY AGGD.[NVP NAME],AGGD.NVP,[BASE PERIOD]
    UNION
    SELECT AGGD.NVP, AGGD.[NVP NAME], MIN(AGGD.[CURRENT PERIOD]) AS [MIN PERIOD], [BASE PERIOD]
    FROM AGGDATA AGGD 
    GROUP BY AGGD.[NVP NAME],AGGD.NVP,[BASE PERIOD])  
    AS SUB 
INNER JOIN 

    (SELECT SUB.NVP, 
        SUB.[BASE PERIOD], 
        COUNT([CURRENT PERIOD]) AS [ACTIVE PERIODS]

    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT NVP, [BASE PERIOD], [CURRENT PERIOD]
                FROM AGGDATA) 
        AS SUB

    GROUP BY SUB.NVP, SUB.[BASE PERIOD] 
having COUNT([CURRENT PERIOD]) < 10)  
AS TT 
ON SUB.[BASE PERIOD] = TT.[BASE PERIOD] AND SUB.NVP = TT.NVP
WHERE SUB.[MIN PERIOD] > TT.[BASE PERIOD]
```

Does anyone know why the Union subquery works but the non-unioned subquery doesn't?

EDIT: The two subqueries do produce the same results, the issue is with the whole query.

Thank you!

Comment: The `union`ed version should produce the same results, just with a lot more effort.  My guess is that the two queries you are running are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some issues with your parentheses and aliases.  Try this code instead:

```
SELECT 
    mn.NVP,[NVP NAME], [MIN PERIOD], mn.[BASE PERIOD], TT.[ACTIVE PERIODS]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        [NVP NAME],NVP,[BASE PERIOD], MIN([CURRENT PERIOD]) AS [MIN PERIOD]
    FROM 
        AGGDATA  
    GROUP BY 
        [NVP NAME],NVP,[BASE PERIOD])      AS mn INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        NVP, 
        [BASE PERIOD], 
        COUNT([CURRENT PERIOD]) AS [ACTIVE PERIODS]
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
            NVP, [BASE PERIOD], [CURRENT PERIOD]
          FROM 
            AGGDATA)         AS a
    GROUP BY 
        NVP, [BASE PERIOD] 
    HAVING 
        COUNT([CURRENT PERIOD]) < 10)  AS TT ON 
    mn.[BASE PERIOD] = TT.[BASE PERIOD] AND 
    mn.NVP = TT.NVP
WHERE 
    mn.[MIN PERIOD] > TT.[BASE PERIOD]
```